# To know if you have filed taxes before in Canada?

Tags: income-tax, canada, income-tax-refund, canada-revenue-agency

I am in Canada, I recently filed my taxes with HR block I was supposed to get close to $3500 back accord to HR Block because I hadn't filed for two years(at least I am 95% sure I have).

I just got a payment from CRA and the amount is $1500 short. My question is does CRA direct deposit in installment ie I should wait till the end of next week?

Or should I alert HR Block? Also, in the 2 years I was a student and was done in May 2015. And I worked several jobs.

Next is there a way I could see if I filed my 2014 taxes because like I said Im 95% sure I didn't file. I waited to do it all this year (and yes I know I should be doing my taxes every year)

Answer (score 2):

The folks at CRA are astonishingly helpful. As in you get off the phone and say to yourself "was that really a government employee I was talking to?" [Get in touch with them](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rfnds/menu-eng.html) and ask.

You can set up access to your account online, or call in and talk to a person. Of course, you'll need to be able to [prove you are the right person](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/cntct/phn-eng.html#h0_1) to discuss this with, so in addition to your SIN, birthdate, address and other personal information, they will want some numbers from paperwork they've sent you. Gather that up before getting in touch.

The most important thing you should have is a Notice of Assessment. This will explain why you got the amount you did, and also provide the numbers you need to identify yourself to the CRA. If you didn't get this, but money has just magically appeared in your bank account, wait a few days for the NoA to appear. If it still hasn't appeared then confirm with HR Block what address it was to go to. Sorting this out with the CRA will be harder without it.